# WordPress WP_Query Meta_key with orderby meta_value_num not working properly

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following WP_Query (output from var_dump):

```
array(7) { ["post_type"]=> string(4) "post" ["ignore_sticky_posts"]=> bool(false) ["posts_per_page"]=> int(5) ["orderby"]=> string(14) "meta_value_num" ["order"]=> string(4) "DESC" ["meta_type"]=> string(7) "NUMERIC" ["meta_key"]=> string(17) "vw_post_views_all" }
```

What it's supposed to do is grab the top 5 viewed posts. The view data is stored in the vw_post_views_all meta key. I checked the database, and some posts that have higher values are not being displayed in the 5 that show. I checked out other stackoverflow posts, and some people recommended using `"meta_type" => "numeric"`, but I tried that and it didn't change anything.

One thing I did notice is that the meta value is being saved in the DB as longtext, rather than a number. We have some very old posts with several thousand views. For example, one post has 20985, yet a post with 4700 views is being shown instead. This seems to me like the query is not sorting by integer values correctly, as 4 is indeed higher than 2, but 4700 is not higher than 20985. I'm not sure how I can convert all of these meta values into int values in the DB, though.

Or perhaps, the query simply isn't retrieving the posts because they are several years old? We have many posts...could it be an issue with WP_Query? I tried updating the 20k value to 5k, and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue! The Post Types Order plugin that I had installed was hijacking the query. After deactivating the plugin, the query worked as expected.

Note, if someone is reading and has a similar issue, at the time of writing, that plugin offers a setting that automatically allows the plugin to hijack the query on all loops across the site. You can disable that, and then manually use `"orderby" => "menu_order"` in your queries that you want this plugin to affect. Unfortunately, that did not work for me on this specific site, but I seem to recall having success using that on other sites in the past.